# Displaying modal dialog only once, then not displaying again until user has cleared cache or cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, caching, cookies

Displaying modal dialog only once, then not displaying again until user has cleared cache or cookies.

I have a modal dialog that I'd like to display when a user visits my website, but only once. If the user closes out of it or uses it, I'd like to not display it again for a very long time.

My jsFiddle is at:
http://jsfiddle.net/B84tq/

My html is:

```
  <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
  <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
      <h3 id="myModalLabel">Email Deals</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Sign up for email-only specials and news updates. We will not sell or rent your email address.</p>
        <p>Sign up now!</p>
          <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="http://www.gliq.com/cgi-bin/subunsub">
          <div class="input-prepend">
          <input type="hidden" name="acctname" value="amleo"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="subscribe"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://www.amleo.com/subscribe-successful/a/47/"/>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Your email address" id="inputIcon" class="input-xlarge" name="email">
          <input value="SUBSCRIBE" class="btn btn-orange" type="submit">
          </div>
          </form>
        <p><a href=" [[DMI:Control name='FriendlyUrlArticleSiteMap' dmisource='Core.GetContentByNumber("3")']][[/DMI:Control]]">Privacy Policy</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: So your question is how to use cookie??? What about searching for it, there are thousand sample codes on how to use cookies over the net...

Answer (score 0):

Use cookies.

You can google how to handle cookies in js.

eg. in pseudocode

```
if (document.cookies['testvalX']!=1)
{
   //display modal
   document.cookies[] = 'testvalX=1';
}
```

Comment: What is the most modern way to handle cookies? I'm seeing a ton of articles from 2003 & 2008. Also, pseudocode doesn't help much if I have no idea of what the actual code is :(